# Why sometimes cnosdb cannot delete the tenant, but it is fine after restarting?

Tags: cnosdb

I have a cnosdb cluster running for more than 30 days, when I want to delete a tenant, the return value is that the `tenant does not exist`. But I can find the tenant from the tenants table. When I restart the cluster, it can be deleted normally again. So where is the problem? It feels like an accidental event and it is difficult to reproduce.